# Google Maps myLocationButton is under Tab Bar Controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

Using sample code from Google's Developer page I have implemented maps into my app. The map view is under both a navigation controller and tab bar controller. How can I resize the map so it does not overlap these? This would not be a huge issue except for the fact that the myLocationButton is half under the tab bar controller.

Comment: Are you doing it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up fixing this by setting the bottom padding = 44. Didn't know this option was there at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your UIView where your mapview is on. Hope it helps.